# Importing class in GAE (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I know it's a very dumb question. And it's all about the very basics.
But unfortunately I'm very very short on time and can't read a Python book right now.

I have this issue.
Well in GAE you a root main.py script.

And I have two classes which are stored in:
htmlparser/HTMLParser
htmlParser/BfsHTMLParser

And I cannot import them into main.py

What am I doing wrong?

I'm doing:

```
import htmlparser
```

But I catch:

> NameError: global name 'BfsHTMLParser' is not defined

Would appreciate any help. Thank you.

p.s. I would also appreciate any book advice about Python basics like this :)

Comment: I also tried `import htmlparser.BfsHTMLParser` — i get `NameError: global name 'BfsHTMLParser' is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from htmlparser import HTMLParser, BfsHTMLParser
```

**Edit** I'm afraid this is really basic Python stuff, and you aren't going to get far without reading a Python tutorial. Python is not Java, and the problem here is that you've imported the modules, but not the classes - in Python they are not the same thing.

If you've got classes named the same as the module files, now that you've imported the modules, you will need to instantiate them via `HTMLParser.HTMLParser` or `BfsHTMLParser.BfsHtmlParser`. Of course, really you shouldn't package classes like that, but that's the situation you have.

Comment: Thank you!But now I catch `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: thanks. But how should a package classes? I'm used to this logical hierarchy from ActionScript and Java, yes. And I have a freedom to package them in other way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got an `__init__.py` in the htmlparser directory ??

Comment: No-o-o :) But what should it contain?

Comment: Try just a blank file to start with

Comment: I get then `line 58, in get
    parser = BfsHTMLParser()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, currently I switched to BeautifulSoup
Put the BeatifulSoup in the root and it's working.

But still the question of packaging logical code blocks remains open.